# GKE: Standard tier load balancer

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, gcp-load-balancer

I'd like to downgrade the load balancer of my GKE Service from Premium tier, to Standard tier. To do that, I added `cloud.google.com/network-tier: Standard` to the annotations of my service. The problem now is that no load balancer is getting created in the `Load Balancer` section, and I can't connect to my kubernetes service anymore.

The service itself was installed by helm, but here's the resulting YAML from GKE:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  annotations:
    cloud.google.com/neg: '{"ingress":true}'
    cloud.google.com/network-tier: Standard
    meta.helm.sh/release-name: ingress-nginx
    meta.helm.sh/release-namespace: ingress-nginx
  creationTimestamp: "2023-03-29T22:15:04Z"
  finalizers:
  - service.kubernetes.io/load-balancer-cleanup
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/component: controller
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/part-of: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/version: 1.5.1
    helm.sh/chart: ingress-nginx-4.4.2
  name: ingress-nginx-controller
  namespace: ingress-nginx
spec:
  allocateLoadBalancerNodePorts: true
  clusterIP: 10.70.128.216
  clusterIPs:
  - 10.70.128.216
  externalTrafficPolicy: Cluster
  internalTrafficPolicy: Cluster
  ipFamilies:
  - IPv4
  ipFamilyPolicy: SingleStack
  loadBalancerIP: <<REDACTED>>
  ports:
  - name: http
    nodePort: 31109
    port: 80
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: http
  - name: https
    nodePort: 31245
    port: 443
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: https
  selector:
    app.kubernetes.io/component: controller
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
  sessionAffinity: None
  type: LoadBalancer
status:
  loadBalancer: {}
```

Comment: What is the error message? Is the `loadBalancerIP` global or regional? For a Standard class load balancer the IP address must be regional. If you did not reallocate a new address and are using the same IP address as the Premium class, that will cause a failure.

Comment: Turns out the this was the problem after all, thanks for the quick reply

Comment: I can accept it as solution, if you write an answer

Comment: You and I were writing at the same time. Go ahead and mark your answer and I will upvote it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution, the problem was that my reserved IP address was of premium tier. Now that I changed it, everything seems to be in working order